# PHP display data in table using foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have the 2020 hurricane name and all the states. I want to loop through my database and see if the options are picked. If they are, populate the spot with the name. If not, add"--". It will look almost like a spreadsheet of data.

When I submit data, it doesn't populate in the right spot and add a bunch of empty cells.

This is my queries:

```
// DB Connection
$db_connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','hurricane_bowl');

    $i = "SELECT * FROM users RIGHT JOIN states USING (state_id) GROUP BY (state_name) ORDER BY state_name ASC";
$state = mysqli_query($db_connection, $i);

$g = "SELECT * FROM users RIGHT JOIN hurricanes USING (hurricane_id) GROUP BY (hurricane_name) ORDER BY hurricane_name ASC";
$hurricane = mysqli_query($db_connection, $g);
```

This is my loops:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Hurricane Name</th>
                        <?php
                        foreach($state as $stval) {

                            echo '<th scope="col">' . $stval['state_name'] . '</th>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    foreach($hurricane as $h) {
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<th scope="row">' . $h['hurricane_name'] . '</th>';
                        foreach($state as $st) {
                            if($st['state_id'] != NULL && $h['hurricane_id'] != NULL) {
                                echo '<td>' . $st['username'] . '</td>';
                            } else {
                                echo '<td>--</td>';
                            }
                        }
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }

                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Because as you consume ALL of the users for the first iteration of State, and ALL states for each iteration of Hurricane

Comment: Unless these tables are logically linked in some way, this is just data not knowledge

Comment: Plus the first foreach consumes all the States even before you get into the big set of loops

Comment: Please do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` for each of these tables and copy/paste the output to your question

Comment: You didn't close the <tr> that comes right after foreach($hurricane_result as $value)....

Comment: I revised my table result query to a join statement and the table to only two foreach loops, but it is telling me the $table_data_result isn't an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first change needs to be to the queries: if you want to display three separate query results, you need three separate tables, otherwise it makes not sense because there is no connection between the three datasets you are retrieving. Alternatively, you need just one dataset. Use `JOIN` in a query to link multiple table results, assuming there is a link between the tables.

W3Schools on this topic: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Secondly, when loops are nested, each layer is its own dimension. In your case, you are trying to create a sort of 3-dimensional table, which can't work. Typically for a query result you only need one `foreach` loop, but if you don't have any information on the table fields, you can have two, not more.

Comment: The users table has two foreign keys: state_id and hurricane_id. Is this query correct? SELECT username
FROM users
INNER JOIN states USING state_id
INNER JOIN hurricanes USING hurricane_id
ORDER BY states.state_name ASC

Comment: It is saying that the query isn't an array. How would you loop through the query then? Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand if this query works without seeing your schema. Can you add it to the question? Also, are you familiar with PHPMyAdmin? You can try running your query there to see what results you get, and tweak it accordingly. Finally, you still use two separate queries in nested `foreach` loops. If you're getting all the data in one query, there shouldn't be another nested one.

Comment: How can we display a piece of data like a coordinate along the x and y axis with one loop? I have updated the queries and the table code in the question. the whole columns is repeating the same name so it is close but I am lost as to how to get it correct.